# J-Link device selection error in Keil

Tags: stm32, arm, keil, cortex-m0, j-link

I try to load a program into STM32L011K4 using J-Link. The mistakes I get and the steps I follow are as follows:

**PROBLEM-1.** J-link could not find STM32L011K4

#### My Steps:

- Click options for *Target* → *Utilities* → *Debug Settings* → *Add Unspecified Device* (Cortex M0+)
- Click options for *Target* → *Utilities* → *Debug Settings* → Port (SW) and click <kbd>OK</kbd>.

**PROBLEM-2.** When I click to load (<kbd>F8</kbd>) the program, I got an  error as below:

> "JLink-Cortex Error: Flash Timeout.Reset the Target and try it again"

and I clicked <kbd>OK</kbd>.

Then I get an error like this:

> "uVision: Error:Flash Download failed - "Cortex-M0+"

#### My Steps:

I changed *Options For Target* → *Target IROM1 and IRAM1 values*, but I kept getting the same error. Also I tried to change values of *Options For Target* → *Debug Settings* → *Max Clock*, but nothing has changed.

[image: Problem 2]

Comment: What kind of board is it? Is it a reference board, one you made? Are you sure the chip works?

Comment: J-Link board version=9.2  (13-44;YY-WW). And I am sure chip is working, because I can load program and debug with used ST-Link/V2.